# Adding a Page Layout to the drop-down menu on the ribbon

Tags: 2013, page-layout, ribbon, custom-masterpage

**Background:**

I have created a custom page layout for my SharePoint 2013 site.

**Problem:**

I want to add the newly created page layout to the "Page Layout" drop-down menu within the Page ribbon.  Is it possible to add layouts to this menu so it can be easily changed by my users?

Image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to go into Site Settings and click the `Page layouts and site templates` link in the Look and Feel section. Check the Page layots section to see if it is set to only use specific layouts, if so, select your page layout and click the Add button then click OK to save the changes.